# In visual studio, In the project properties of c++ project, what is the reference window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, reference, project

It's probably a question that many asked , but i can't find any answer.

What is this window, can he replace manually adding "addition include folders" and "addition linker folders" ? 
why and when should i use it (let's say i work with openCV or other third party)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: i don't have vs 2010 installed on this machine, but try F1 for help

Comment: only got 2008 here, but c/c++ page, 1st line

Comment: This is for C++/CLI projects, to reference .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Additional Dependencies instead but if it's another project within your solution it's better to add it as a reference because that will ensure the correct build order. If it's a third-party static library (.lib) you can only use Additional Dependencies. Although the screenshot you show is for C++/CLI projects, where you can also add references to .NET assemblies and COM components.

Comment: So in fact it's the same like additional dependencies ? just more convenient ?